# How to split a string and summarize the parts into a new numeric variable in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have several datasets with a stringvariable that is the result of a concatenation of up to four numeric variables. The variables looks like something like my example below:

[image]

I need to create a new numeric variable which contains the sum of "ParSokBel". I have no need for information about the different parts or how many they are in the future use of this data.

In the next step I will loop the solution several times. There might be more than four values in a single row in some of the following datasets.

The variable is in a datastructure which contain between 61-75 attributes (varies up and down with tablegeneration).

I realy don't want to import the data again and I'm not realy shure how I would have done this anyway, since some of the other attributes contain commas and should do so.

Anyone who have an idea of how I can solve this? I can'n show an example code because I dont have any. I'm not even shure where to begin since I've never encountered something like this before.

I'm using MSN SQL Server Express and MSN SQL Server 2014 (they are both used but in different parts of the dataproduction process where Server Express handles the import and Server 2014 is the global environment for our system). I have greater freedom/rights in the Express environment than in the Server 2014 environment.

Comment: Those aren't variables, they're rows. The real problem here is you are storing delimited data representing numbers. This means you have a `varchar` storing the value, so, in your data, the "highest" value you have is `'400000'` (as that is the string that starts with the highest number and has the longest length). Plus the fact that you you can't appy the `SUM` function to a `varchar` as well means need a lot of work before you can aggregate your data. you really need to fix your design.

Comment: I know. If I had access to the source data I would have done it in a different way. But, I don't have access to the system that delivers the data. It comes from an external source that is delivered exclusivly for my employer. I don't know why they have delivered the data in this way. The last delivery it was'nt and I have asked if they could redeliver the earlier data, but they could'nt. So, I'm stuck with this structure and need to find a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use `string_split()` in the latest versions of SQL Server:

```
select sum(try_convert(int, ss.val))
from t cross apply
     string_split(parsokbel, ',') ss(val);
```

If you have an older version of SQL Server, you can peruse the web for a `split()` function.

Comment: Thanks. This partly helped me. My db-engine did'nt recognize "string_split", but this helped me to move on. I'll search further on split functions. The ones I've found before I posted my question ended up with putting the values in different rows, but I try to search again and this time from a "string_split" perspective.

Comment: [Here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) are several excellent splitters.